# Joomla CiviCRM Upgrade 4.3.9 to 4.4.x version

Tags: upgrade, database

I am unable to upgrade 4.3.9 version into new version ..

I am getting this error : Error: Consolidate activity contacts

```
Type    DB_Error
Code    -2
Message DB Error: syntax error
Mode    16
UserInfo    UPDATE civicrm_option_value SET is_reserved = 1 WHERE option_group_id = 62 AND value IN (2, , 3) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 3)' at line 3]
DebugInfo   UPDATE civicrm_option_value SET is_reserved = 1 WHERE option_group_id = 62 AND value IN (2, , 3) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 3)' at line 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you may have deleted the 'Activity Assignees' option from the 'activity_contacts' option group. That's what the missing id is supposed to refer to in `IN (2, , 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in your database to see what value it's referring to? I had a database problem when upgrading (not these specific versions) and I had to remove the apostrophe in my organization's name for the upgrade to run successfully. Also, if you've not already tried, I'd recommend incremental upgrades, see if smaller steps like 4.3.9 to 4.3.10 works.

Comment: Would be great if you reported the upgrade error message you saw to a new ticket on issues.civicrm.org, that sounds like something worth fixing!